# Prove that this space of stochastic processes is complete

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

See page 17 on
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/notes/lecture-19.pdf

We define $\mathcal{QM}(T)$ to be the space of all non-anticipating processes $X$ such that the norm $||X||_{{QM}(T)}$ defined by
\begin{align}
(||X||_{{QM}(T)})^2 = \mathbb{E} [ \sup_{ t \in [0,T]} (X_t)^2 ]
\end{align}
is finite. Then, it says that this space is complete with respect to this norm, and that the proof is analogous to the proof that the space $L^2$ is complete. I was able to mimic the proof of the completeness of $L^2$ and I (think) that I found a process $Y$ such that $(||X-Y||_{{QM}(T)})^2$ has limit $0$. But, in my particular application, I also require that all processes in $\mathcal{QM}(T)$ have continuous sample paths. I am trying to prove that the process $Y$ also has this property, but this is where I am stuck. Please could somebody offer some help? Many thanks.